# Maven + Jaxb Marshalling Accent Characters + Unit Test

Tags: maven, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I currently have a unit test that is unmarshalling an XML file into Jaxb objects then marshalling it to a string and comparing it with the original xml string:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/info/info-element-reader-test-context.xml"})
public class InfoElementReaderTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InfoElementReaderTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private InfoElementReader infoElementReader;

    @Test
    public void testMarshalling() throws Exception {

        Marshaller marshaller = infoElementReader.getJaxbContext().createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        // Unmarshall into java bean
        InfoElement infoElement = infoElementReader.unmarshallInfoElement();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        marshaller.marshal(infoElement, outStream);
        logger.info("marshalled XML: {}", outStream.toString());

        String fromFile = IOUtils.toString(infoElementReader.getInfoResource().getInputStream(), "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\s","");

        String marshalled = outStream.toString().replaceAll("&quot;", "\"").replaceAll("\\s","");

        assertEquals("file contents should equal marshalled output", fromFile, marshalled);
    }
}
```

When I run this test in my IDE (Intellij IDEA) it appears to have no issues but when I compile with mvn clean package this unit test fails because all the accented characters in the XML, ie. Reddetelefoníamóvil, become Reddetelefon[?am?vil and the strings are obviously not equal.

Not sure if this is an issue with maven or something else but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Encoding within the pom File?
UTF-8